# Include and access spatial data in R package

Tags: r, spatial, r-package

I'm re-writing some R scripts that process and analyze spatial data into a package so that it will be easier to share. Initially I had just saved all the raster data/etc as TIFFs onto my working directory, and loaded it from there into the script each time I wanted to do an analysis using "stack" or "raster". What's the equivalent for a R package? I have a lot of rasters/shapefiles, some of which are quite large.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html

Comment: Have a look at `sf`  package

Comment: I can read and write the spatial data in R, but the problem is that it is saved something like "username/data.tiff", so a command like raster(data.tiff) won't work if I'm writing a package, right? Because whoever else is using the package won't have the file saved in the same location. So I'm wondering where/how to save the data within this new package I am writing, and how to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at other packages. For example, this is what you see in `raster`

```
library(raster)
?raster
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
```

It finds the file "external/test.grd" relative to the root of the installed package --- so that it works for all users, irrespective of the path to the package.

As you can see in the raster source code: https://github.com/rspatial/raster
`external` is a subfolder of `inst` in the package source. You can give `external` any name, as long you put it in the `inst` folder.

If at all possible, use example files from other packages that your package depends on, such as `raster` in this case.

Comment: Yes, I think this works for me! I think, also, I need to re-arrange my code more so that most of the spatial data will be used as inputs into the package functions, and then I just supply the raw spatial data as a separate folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting together a R package then this is a great resource and will help you figure out what goes where: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/. Essentially, you would put it in the `data` folder within your package.

If you have loads of large rasters though it will be hard to release the package publicly. If the rasters/shapefiles are already being hosted somewhere on the internet though you could just incorporate calls to those weblinks.